# I break the vba formula in 4 pieces still I am getting error "Unable to set formulaArray property of range classe"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, stack-overflow

I have broke the vba formula in 4 piece but still when I run the code it gives the error "Unable to set the formulaArray property of range class". Please let me know what is wrong with my vba formula. I am using Excel 2016 version.
Appreciate your support. Below is my vba formula and vba code:

array formula:

```
    Selection.FormulaArray =_ 
    "=IF(ROWS(Template!R16C:RC)>R8C6,"""",INDEX(THICK!R3C1:R1000C[-2],SMALL(IF(THICK!R3C1:R1000C1>=Template!R7C3,IF(THICK!R3C1:R1000C1<=Template!R8C3,IF(THICK!R3C1:R1000C1>=Template!R9C3,IF(THICK!R3C1:R1000C1<=Template!R10C3,ROW(THICK!R3C1:R1000C1)-ROW(THICK!R3C1)+1)))),ROWS(Template!R16C:RC))))"
```

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim theFormulaPart1 As String
Dim theFormulaPart2 As String
Dim theFormulaPart3 As String
Dim theFormulaPart4 As String

theFormulaPart1 = "=IF(ROWS(Template!R16C:RC)>R8C6,"""",INDEX(THICK!R3C1:R1000C[-2],""66,66"",""77,77"",""88))),88)))"""

theFormulaPart2 = "SMALL(IF(THICK!R3C1:R1000C1>=Template!R7C3,IF(THICK!R3C1:R1000C1<=Template!R8C3,"

theFormulaPart3 = "IF(THICK!R3C1:R1000C1>=Template!R9C3,IF(THICK!R3C1:R1000C1<=Template!R10C3,"

theFormulaPart4 = "ROW(THICK!R3C1:R1000C1)-ROW(THICK!R3C1)+1)))),ROWS(Template!R16C:RC))))"


With ActiveSheet.Range("C16")
    .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
    .Replace what:="""66,66""", replacement:=theFormulaPart2, lookat:=xlPart
    .Replace what:="""77,77""", replacement:=theFormulaPart3, lookat:=xlPart
    .Replace what:="""88))),88)))"""", replacement:=theFormulaPart4, lookat:=xlPart"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You most likely need to do the string replacement *before* assigning the `FormulaArray` property. My guess is that the initial assignment returns an error, because it's some malformed formula, which your `Replace` is intended to fix.

Comment: Also looks like you have too many `"` in your last `Replace` statement.